# ITHit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

I purchased an ITHit .NET SERVER licence in May 2008, for an ASP.net application, c#, **that works fine when on the client side is MS Office 2003**. 
The documents are stored in a MS Sql Server database and I use a custom IHttpHandler to process the documents.

Since the organisation started to increase, new licences of MS Office (2007/2010/2013) were purchased and instaled on client side.

Although I followed the instruction stated on the page: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only/, couldn`t make it work with MS Office 2007 and further (still opens documents as read-only).

**In order to provide for my client, would it work by aquiring a new licence/upgrade the existing one, or is it possible to fix this issue with the existing licenced version of ITHit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET?**

**Please keep in mind that I need a solution that still have to deal with a mixed environment of MS Office, meaning there still will be used instances of 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013, and even 2016, for the next 3 years.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but a customer support for the software provider

Comment: Got here with this question at the sugestion of a representative of ITHit....